# How to filter Google Analytics to see page stats by categories?

Tags: google, analytics

A website is available in several languages and has several URL categories. I'd like to know the exact number of sessions per category per language.

Site structure:
www.site.com/en/category1/
www.site.com/en/category2/
www.site.com/en/category3/

www.site.com/es/category1/
www.site.com/es/category2/
www.site.com/es/category3/

When a visitor visits one of the URL categories there are thousands URLs that fall under each main URL category. The stats for these individual pages are not needed. Stats are needed for any session which falls under a URL that starts with one of the main URL categories.

Firstly, is it possible, and if it is I would be grateful if someone could show me how to filter Google analytics in order to show me the number of sessions for each of the below URLs.
www.site.com/en/category1/
www.site.com/en/category2/
www.site.com/en/category3/

www.site.com/es/category1/
www.site.com/es/category2/
www.site.com/es/category3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's fairly straightforward. To see data about a single specific URL, go to `Behavior > Site Content > All Pages`. Right underneath the graph, there is a little search box, and you can type in the URL you want to hone in on - i.e. `en/category1`. This first step will pull up its child URLs as well - so next, click on the exact URL whose data you want to view.

At that point, you are viewing data only about the single, specific category URL and not any of its children.

If you should find it useful in the future to view stats for child URLs - say, all Spanish traffic combined - you can use `Behavior > Site Content > Content Drilldown` and click on `es` to see all data about visits to the Spanish site.